# How to collect data every ten seconds onto the same CSV file using tkinter

Tags: python, loops, csv, user-interface, tkinter

I am using python for a GUI and want to collect temperature in a range of 40 minutes. I want the program to save the data to a csv the same csv file every 10 seconds. for some reason my code saves 10 csv files or 10 seconds rather than 1 csv file with 10 data points.

#

```
def start(): # Stores Data Initial Columns
with open(txtName + time.strftime('%H:%M:%S', time.localtime()) + '.csv', 
'a') as data: 
        output = csv.writer(data)
        row = ['Time' , 'Left Hand Temp' , 'Right Hand Temp' , 'Fluid 
Temp Into Handle' , 'Fluid Temp Out of Handle' ]
        output.writerow(row)

def collect(): # Stores Data File Name With User Input    
with open(txtName + time.strftime('%H:%M:%S', time.localtime()) + '.csv', 
'a') as data:

##### THIS IS MY ATTEMPT AT A 10 second loop #######
 for everysecond in range(60):
     if everysecond % 10 is 0:
        output = csv.writer(data)
        rows = [time.strftime('%H:%M:%S', time.localtime()), 
sensor1.temperature, sensor2.temperature, 
sensor3.read_temp_c(),sensor4.read_temp_c()]
        output.writerow(rows)
#### I Think this is where the code for the 10 second loop should go, For 
some reason i cant get it to take data with respect to computer time. 

#Window
topFrame= Frame(root)
topFrame.pack()
bottomframe = Frame(root)
bottomframe.pack(side=BOTTOM)

#################### Buttons ##########################

button1 = Button(topFrame,text="Start Work-out", bg ='blue', command = 
start)
button2 = Button(topFrame,text="Collect", bg ='green', command = collect)
exitbutton = Button(root, bg = 'red', text='Stop Work-out', command = 
root.destroy)  

button1.pack(side = LEFT)
button2.pack()
```

Should save/ update data to same csv file every 10 seconds

Comment: `for everysecond in range(60):` will finish in an instant.

Comment: You can use `after` method to call `collect` function every 10 seconds

Comment: As you have used current time as part of the output filename, you will create a new file when you click `Start` and `Collect` buttons.  However there should be six records written to the output file when you click `Collect` button.